# Login Authentication with navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am new to react native .. I made only an UI for a restaurant app and now converting all static components to a dynamic ones ... My first step > how to make a login authentication and when logged in navigate specific screen ?

**ــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ**

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

import { Container, Content, Form, Item, Label, Linking, Icon, Text, Button, Input } from 'native-base';
import styles from './../../styles/Login/login'
import PasswordTextBox from './passwordInput'
import {
  useNavigation,
  useRoute,
  useFocusEffect,
  useNavigationState
} from '@react-navigation/native';

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'

LoginForm = () => {

return (

  <Container style={styles.containerStl} >
  <Content showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
    <View style={styles.viewStl}>
        <Text style={styles.titleStl}>Sign In</Text>
      <Form style={styles.formStl} >
        <Item style={styles.formStl} stackedLabel>
            <Label style={styles.labelStl}>Email ID</Label>
            <Input regular    
            placeholder='sample@emailid.com'
            placeholderTextColor="#e3e3e3" 
            style={styles.inputStl} 
        />
        </Item>
        <Item style={styles.formStl} stackedLabel>
            <Label style={styles.labelStl}>Password</Label>
            <PasswordTextBox icon="lock" label="New Password"  />

          </Item>
        <Text style={styles.forgotStl} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Forgot Password', { screenName: "Forgot Password" })}>Forgot Password?</Text>
        <Button style={styles.btnStl} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile View', { screenName: "Profile View" })}>
          <Text style={styles.centerTxt}>Sign In</Text>
        </Button>
        
        <Text style={styles.notMember} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Sign Up', { screenName: "Sign Up" })} >Not yet a member, <Text style={styles.notSignup} >Sign Up</Text></Text>
      </Form>
      </View>

    </Content>
  </Container>

);
  }

  export default LoginForm;
```

**ــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ**

*I am using react-navigation for routing*

**App.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import {  StatusBar } from 'react-native';


import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native'
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack'
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs'
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs'


import LoginForm from './components/Login/login'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();


const LoginStack = createStackNavigator();

function LoginStackScreen() {
  return (
    <LoginStack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerShown: false
    }}>
      <LoginStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginForm} />
      <LoginStack.Screen name="Registeration" component={RegForm} />
      <LoginStack.Screen name="Forgot Password" component={ForgotPass} />
      <LoginStack.Screen name="Corp Login" component={corpLogin} />
      <LoginStack.Screen name="Corp Registration" component={CorpRegForm} />
      <LoginStack.Screen name="Corp Forgot Password" component={CorpforgotPass} />
    </LoginStack.Navigator>
  );
}

createHomeStack = () =>
 <Stack.Navigator   screenOptions={{
     headerShown: false
   }}
 >
  <Stack.Screen name="Lines Portal" component={LinesPortal} />
 </Stack.Navigator>



export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
     return (
      <LoginForm />
     )
  }
}
```

**ــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــــ**

*As I said before I am new on react native and self learning no one follows up on me or asking for help to guide me .. so I have only you guys*

**Another question** .. How to use **'constructor'** and **'this'** with arrow function component ?

Answer (score 0):

How to use 'constructor' and 'this' with arrow function component?

```
you use the useState hook to do the same thing. For example:
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);
```

this line of code sets the initial value of isLoggedIn to false, then create a function setIsLoggedIn to set the value. i.e.

```
setIsLoggedIn(true);
```

this is the equivalent of below in a class component.

```
this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});
```

There are many things missing in your code, so I will summarize the approach in the authentication flow using React Navigation. for reference, you can look at this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

first, you need to have a state (store variable preferred using react context or redux) that signify if the user is logged in or not. Let use isLoggedIn.

```
isLoggedIn ? (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
  </>
) : (
  <>
    <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUpScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="ResetPassword" component={ResetPassword} />
  </>
);
```

then in your Login screen, you modify this same state variable isLoggedIn to true/false depending on the status of the log in process. When the variable isLoggedIn is true, the Home and Profile components will be rendered instead of the Signin and Signup components.